# Bootstrap caroucel could not active 2 carousel-indicators

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a slider by bootstap caroucel
i add 2 "carousel-indicators" to my slider, one for top and one for bottom, it work well, but the carousel indicators at the bottom could not active when I'm clicking on it
here is my code for 2 carousel-indicators:

```html
<ol id="carou-top" class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-top">
    
   
                <li class="" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
                <li class="active" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
           
  </ol>

<ol id="carou-bottom" class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-bottom">
    
   
                <li class="" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
                <li class="" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
           
  </ol>
```

how can i add class "active" to the bottom
[image: image for demo]
many thanks

Comment: Did you try to add `active` class to your last `li` tag?

Comment: Yes.i have added class "active" to my li tag to both of them(carousel-indicators-bottom and carousel-indicators-top)

Comment: Bootstrap does not support that. You have to use JavaScript/jQuery to achieve your goal. Good way will be to find number of the current active slide, then add active class to appropriate `li` in your second set of carousel indicators.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with that code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://www.gettyimages.fr/gi-resources/images/frontdoor/creative/PanoramicImagesRM/FD_image.jpg" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.gettyimages.fr/gi-resources/images/frontdoor/creative/PanoramicImagesRM/FD_image.jpg" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.gettyimages.fr/gi-resources/images/frontdoor/creative/PanoramicImagesRM/FD_image.jpg" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-custom">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

JS:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {

  var resetTimeout;
  clearTimeout(resetTimeout);

  var i = 0;
  var activeSlideNumber = 0;
  var carouselIndicatorsDefault = $(this).find('.carousel-indicators > li');
  var carouselIndicatorsCustom = $('.carousel-indicators-custom > li');

  resetTimeout = setTimeout(function () {

    for (i = 0; i < carouselIndicatorsDefault.length; i++) {

      if (carouselIndicatorsDefault.eq(i).hasClass('active')) {
        activeSlideNumber = i;
      }

    }

    carouselIndicatorsCustom.removeClass('active');
    carouselIndicatorsCustom.eq(activeSlideNumber).addClass('active');

   }, 20);

});
```

For loop in JS checks if your default carousel indicator has class of active (when the slide changes) and store number of this slide to the `activeSlideNumber` variable. Then it removes all active classes from your custom indicators and add only to the active one.

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmERox)